# Why I do not work correctly buttons start time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-video

I use mediaelementplayer

My code (why doesn't it work here)

```js
(function() {

  'use strict';

  let media;
  let mediaBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".button-play");
  let mediaBtnPause = document.querySelectorAll(".button-pause");
  let mediaTime;
  let mediaTimeParts;
  let mediaTimeSeconds;

  $("iframe").mediaelementplayer({
    success: function(mediaElement, domObject) {
      media = mediaElement;
    }
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < mediaBtn.length; i++) {

    let mediaBtns = mediaBtn[i];

    mediaTime = mediaBtns.innerHTML;

    mediaTimeParts = mediaTime.split(':');

    mediaTimeSeconds = (+mediaTimeParts[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+mediaTimeParts[1]) * 60 + (+mediaTimeParts[2]);

    //console.log(i + ' ' + mediaTimeSeconds);

    mediaBtns.addEventListener('click', function() {
      media.setCurrentTime(mediaTimeSeconds);
      media.play();

      console.log('Click button # ' + i);
    });

  }


})();
```

```css
button {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mediaelement/4.2.9/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mediaelement/4.2.9/mediaelementplayer.min.css">

<!-- video 1 -->
<div class="media-wrapper">
  <iframe class="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HIbAz29L-FA?modestbranding=1&playsinline=0&showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fintercoin.org&widgetid=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

  <button class="button-play">00:00:10</button>
  <button class="button-play">00:00:20</button>
  <button class="button-pause">pause</button>
</div>
<!-- video 1 -->
```

Example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5a7yoe8c/)

now it turns out when you click on any button (except for a pause) - the start starts from the value of the last button. In this example, from 20 seconds.

For example, when you click on the button `"<button class="button-play"> 00:00:10</button>"` - the video starts from 20 seconds (from the value of the last button)

Why it happens?

How to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Because mediaTimeSeconds is reassigned everytime you run the for loop. Therefore it is assigned with the last value, while the button is clicked after it is assigned. You need to change it to

```
(function() {

  'use strict';

  let media;
  let mediaBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".button-play");
  let mediaBtnPause = document.querySelectorAll(".button-pause");
  let mediaTime;
  let mediaTimeParts;

  $("iframe").mediaelementplayer({
    success: function(mediaElement, domObject) {
      media = mediaElement;
    }
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < mediaBtn.length; i++) {

    let mediaBtns = mediaBtn[i];

    mediaTime = mediaBtns.innerHTML;

    mediaTimeParts = mediaTime.split(':');

    const mediaTimeSeconds = (+mediaTimeParts[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+mediaTimeParts[1]) * 60 + (+mediaTimeParts[2]);

    //console.log(i + ' ' + mediaTimeSeconds);

    mediaBtns.addEventListener('click', function() {
      media.setCurrentTime(mediaTimeSeconds);
      media.play();

      console.log('Click button # ' + i);
    });

  }


})();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I have another question https://jsfiddle.net/5a7yoe8c/1/ If add second block from the video, the buttons also apply to the last block from the video.

Comment: I think because of this line ```media = mediaElement;```. It assign the media to the last one